# Without installing snapd, How to install ubuntu software centre?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, software-center

I have removed `snapd` from ubuntu 20.04 because it uses high amount of memory, I want to install software center without installing `snapd`,I tried `sudo apt install ubuntu-software`, but it also install `snapd`,
is there a way to do it, or `snapd` is essential dependency for software center ?

Comment: Ubuntu Software in 20.04 and newer is ONLY available as a Snap. Either reinstall snapd or choose a different method of browsing software.

Comment: You can use synaptic. `sudo apt install synaptic`

Comment: There are a few other software stores also, I find app grid works well.

Comment: Not really sure how `snapd` would be using lots of memory.  Checking my system it is #25 on a list of 30 for the most memory using apps.  `38.9 MiB (0.1%) command: snapd pid: 1554`.  `sudo inxi -t m30` will list the 30 highest memory usage apps.

Comment: @Terrance all tools of snapd i.e. core 18 snap store and others which comes in ubuntu 20.04 were using around 400 MB, so I removed snapd, maybe your are right, the packages run on snapd might consuming the ram, not the snapd itself

Comment: @ParmanandPatidar Snaps do not consume RAM normally.  Out of all the snaps I am running on my system only the `snapd` and the `canonical-livepatch` actually use any RAM.  All the rest use filesystem space as they are mounted as loop files and do not consume RAM until they are called for.  So, `snapd` is the controller and not mounted to the filesystem like all the other snap apps are.  Running the following command will show if any of the mounted snaps are using any RAM:  `sudo inxi -t m1000 | grep "$(df -h | grep snap | awk -F[/] '{print $5}')"` and when I checked mine, only livepatch showed.